# Nginx not serving audio files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've set up a static site behind Nginx, and have a problem serving the audio files.

If I put them in a folder that's a sibling to `index.html` then they can't be found, if I just drop them in next to `index.html` then they are served fine - which is what I have done for now, but naturally, I'd prefer to separate them off. I'm also curious to know what the problem is.

Here is my Nginx conf:

```
▽
server {
    server_name space-invaders.hollyer.me.uk www.space-invaders.hollyer.me.uk;
    listen 80;
    root /home/username/www/html/space-invaders/public;

    location / {
    }

}
```

I've checked the error logs, and here is a snippet, it looks like `/index.html` is being tagged on to the path.

```
[error] 6512#6512: *63 "/home/username/www/html/space-invaders/public/sfx/mothership.wav/index.html" is not found (20: Not a directory)
```

The strange thing is, if I move them out of the `sfx` folder, and just put them in `public` they are served fine (after fixing the paths in the `html`, obviously).

I've tried using another `location` context as follows, but with no joy.

```
location ~ \.wav {
    alias /sfx;
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DOCS on nginx.com could be helpful here. 
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/
Though, I have a feeling you may have already seen the link.

I have not tried to replicate your specific scenario, but see if you can include the index directive.

Comment: Yes I've seen those, tried the `index` directive but Nginx failed to start. Added `index index.html;` above the server context, and wrapped it all in a `http` block - but Nginx won't restart until I revert it back.